# PHP create an array starting by a query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

in my script php i need to format an array end encode it an a json format starting from a select like this:

```
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT datet,vototags,votodom FROM intro_s1 WHERE intro_s1.www = '".$url."' ORDER BY intro_s1.datet DESC");

    $data = array( 
         array('Date', 'v1', 'v2'), 

    );

     while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
         $data[] .= array($row['datet'], $row['vototags'], $row['votodom']);
     }


echo json_encode($data);
```

I need that $ date is as follows:

[[Date,vi,v2],[11/02/2011,12,32],[12/06/2012,99,109][...]

instead my result is:

[["Date","v1","v2"],"Array","Array","Array","Array",[...]

ehat is wrong in my code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Change `$data[] .=` to `$data[] =`.

Comment: Please be aware that the mysql functions have been [deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated) for quite some time now. You should really start moving to mysqli or PDO.

Comment: array_push would be great in this situation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using string concatenation with `.=` on this line:

```
$data[] .= array($row['datet'], $row['vototags'], $row['votodom']);
```

Doing so converts the array into a string which gives you the `Array` value.

If you remove the `.`, it should give you the results you're aiming for:

```
$data[] = array($row['datet'], $row['vototags'], $row['votodom']);
```

Alternatively, if you really want to make sure you're adding a new element into the array, you can use [`array_push()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) (if you don't care about the overhead of a function-call, that is):

```
array_push($data, array($row['datet'], $row['vototags'], $row['votodom']));
```